# Am not able to successfully bind WPF control to C# variable. The resource could not be resolved

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

The statement:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TTColumn}, Path=Names}"
```

gives the error:

> The resource TTColumn could not be resolved.

The entire .xaml code is:

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="XLTT.Views.RemoveColumn"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                        GlowBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"
             ShowTitleBar="False"
             WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" 
             ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
              Height="320" Width="350"   Title="Remove Table Column">
    <controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedSingleRowTabControl.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="20 10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TTColumn}, Path=Names}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedColumn}" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="#FFF1F1F1" Background="#FFFFF9F9" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5 0 5 0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Select Column:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="24"/>


        <Button Name="btnOk" Height="30" Content="Remove" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="68" Command="{Binding RemoveColumnCommand}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Name="btnCancel" Height="30" Content="Close" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="68" RenderTransformOrigin="1.867,0.75" Click="btnCancel_Click" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>

    </Grid>
</controls:MetroWindow>
```

Here is the definition of the `Names` variable that I am trying to bind to WPF.

```
namespace XLTT.Core.Models
{
    public class TTColumn
    {
        private static string[] names = {"one", "two", "three"};   // the name field
        public static string[] Names   // the Name property
        {
            get 
            {
                return names; 
            }
            set 
            {
                names = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to bind a control to a static property you shoud use the `x:Static` [markup extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms742135(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of the `StaticResource` one (since TTColumn is not a static resource).

So you have to add a reference to the namespace in your MetroWindow xaml:

```xml
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="XLTT.Views.RemoveColumn"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             ...
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:XLTT.Core.Models"
```

then replace your binding with:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static models:TTColumn.Names}}"
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define an XAML namespace for `XLTT.Core.Models` and reference it in the `StaticResource` extension. For this, we need to know the assembly name that the namespace is declared in - ill refer to this as `SampleNamespace`

First add the namespace to the `MetroWindow` element.

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="XLTT.Views.RemoveColumn"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:XLTT.Core.Models;assembly=SampleNamespace"
```

Now reference the namespace in the binding.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource models:TTColumn}, Path=Names}"
```